# Haskell RGB to CMYK

Tags: haskell, colors

```
rgb2cmyk r g b = ((w - (r/255))/w,(w - (g/255))/w,(w - (b/255))/w,k = 1 - w)
            where   w = max(r/255,g/255,b/255)
```

Could please someone help me with the code? No matter what I do, I get the same Failure "parse error on input '='"

Answer (score 2):

Don't use tabs, indentation is significant in Haskell, so use spaces. Something like the following ([max](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=max) takes only two arguments, maximum takes a list).

```
rgb2cmyk r g b = ((w - (r/255))/w, (w - (g/255))/w, (w - (b/255))/w, 1 - w)
  where
    w = maximum [r/255, g/255, b/255]
```